# Eclipse .XML files not showing ANY text

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The past couple of days I've been having problems with Eclipse, such as appcompact_v7 making a new compact after each problem. Then App_compact wouldn't transfer the .jar files over automatically. NOW I'm having another problem, which is everytime I start a new Android Application Project the textView that says "Hello World!" is "invisible". It says it's on the layout, but it's not visible. Next problem i'm having is that anytime I add a button, TextView, or anything that has text, it's not visible, no matter what color I use with the text. 1. What is causing eclipse to do this? 2. What can I do to resolve these problems?

We're working on a final project for the class and this determines whether or not i pass the class, so i'm FREAKING out. Here is what my project looks like and what its showing : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the theme on top it AppTheme by default. Try using any `Holo.Light` themes and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked. I'm still having issues with App_compact duplicating, and not wanting to pull .jar files.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on last week.

Solution: update your Android SDK and check updates in Eclipse. If it's not work try backup projects and reinstall Android SDK.
Recommend: check locations of files in Android SDK. Google replace SDK files to another location. If it's true, replace files back.

P.S. I have got very bad English. Write comment if it's work. :)